# How can I use higher cost support abilities?

Tags: bravely-default

I'm getting to a point in the game where my characters have several support abilities. I've even gotten one that costs 2 ..."cost"(?). The problem is that I only have one "cost" to use. I might have accidentally skipped a tutorial, but I have no idea how to get more "cost". How does one aquire more "cost"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start the game with one support ability slot and automatically get a new one at the end of each chapter after awakening the crystal, for a total of 5 support slots by the end of Chapter 4. The cost you're referring to corresponds to how many slots the ability takes up.